# CSS error from generated gradient linear gradient from colorzilla editor

Tags: css, gradient

Thank you so much for taking your time to read this.
Heres the code the colorzilla gradient generator created for me:

```
background: #aecc9f; 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #aecc9f 0%, #97b78d 50%, #9bb78d 52%, #8faa83 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #aecc9f 0%,#97b78d 50%,#9bb78d 52%,#8faa83 100%);
**background**: linear-gradient(to bottom, #aecc9f 0%,#97b78d 50%,#9bb78d 52%,#8faa83 100%); 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#aecc9f', endColorstr='#8faa83',GradientType=0 );
```

Next to the line of the bolded background text, I get the following error:

```
Expected (<filter-function-list> | none) but found 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#aecc9f', endColorstr='#8faa83',GradientType=0 )'
```

I hope someone will be kind enough to help a programming idiot such as myself.

Answer (score 0):

Line

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#aecc9f', endColorstr='#8faa83',GradientType=0 );
```

is incorrect, according to definition of `filter` property ([1](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/filter)), it can take following values:

```
blur()
brightness()
contrast()
drop-shadow()
grayscale()
hue-rotate()
invert()
opacity()
saturate()
sepia()
url() - for applying SVG filters
custom() - "coming soon"
```

None of them are responsible for gradient, so you can just remove this line from your code.

Also I don't know what is the purpose of double asterisks around `**background**`, but them break css code, so you probably should remove them too, and it will be like this:

```css
.gradient {
  background: #aecc9f;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #aecc9f 0%, #97b78d 50%, #9bb78d 52%, #8faa83 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #aecc9f 0%,#97b78d 50%,#9bb78d 52%,#8faa83 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #aecc9f 0%,#97b78d 50%,#9bb78d 52%,#8faa83 100%);
}

.wide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wide gradient">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you man, I will delete that line. I had that line bolded with the ** ** just to show that the error appears next to that line

Comment: @JohnHolliday glad to help, if it helped please accept my answer by pressing green check mark to the left of answer